# Trying to switch my lights off in my smart home

Tags: smart-home, communication

My main objective is to make my arduino or create a app on android to control lights in the house.

So my home has the Nexwell Tukan and I can control the lights and power outlets and more, it also has a LAN card with it so it can be controlled with a mobile phone or a PC, the app is called Nexovision. In that program you can control different things by adding them.

So what I need to do is somehow get the packets that the software uses to turn on and off different things and make arduino/the android app send them.

"l.soverom 1" is the name of my room in Nexwell, 6528 is when the lights are on and 0 is when they are off, my PC's IP is the one with 154 and the IoT's is 75.The first lines are the authentication probably,

Here is the link to the [WireShark .pcapng](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-1_1Nl64MjRXk2MGMzNlIwdDA/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Do you have an english version of the manual?

Comment: Goufalite - I don't think there are any manuals, at least in english and also I tried WireShark and got some results and I maybe found how the the packet looks like when the lights are turned on and off, but the problem is that when I send this kind of packet, nothing happens, so I think that it's either that it needs authentication which I don't know how I would do, and what would be the best software to send the packets?

Comment: Can you post the response of the packets you send?

Comment: "l.soverom 1" is the name of my room in Nexwell, 6528 is when the lights are on and 0 is when they are off, my PC's IP is the one with 154 and the IoT's is 75.The first lines are the authentication probably, 

Here is the link to the WireShark .pcapng: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-1_1Nl64MjRXk2MGMzNlIwdDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's proof that it's not a virus: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/0d8f5595f179b1e044d7e89f1b5f550ae7142f19c6fa4bf04c371114d55ccf98/analysis/1490736467/

Comment: A synopsys of the logs (in the question) would help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not looked at the system in detail, but it looks like it really should have properly encrypted/authenticated transmission. This means that unless you can extract the app's private certificate, or otherwise man-in-the-middle the LAN traffic, you won't be able to just tap into the system as you propose. The first sign of this being done right would be observing the transmission as using [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (i.e HTTPS rather than HTTP).

It may be that there is a key exchange happening when you first authenticate a phone onto the system, maybe you can legitimately use this process to acquire the right identification on your Pi.

Does the system have any IFTTT integration? You still shouldn't be able to get direct access, but you can maybe send commands indirectly.

Answer (score 7):

You should start with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for network monitoring. Watch out for headers (authentication, certificates,...)

I think you should use a Raspberry Pi to interface your module, it could be a quite easy-to-configure interface with a web server or a MQTT listener/instance.